# Controller returning 302 in release

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, http, controller

I'm having an issue with ASP.NET MVC. My POST controller method is working fine in localhost and testing environment, but in staging and production, the controller returns a 302 status code.

Before, the controller was an PUT and the return was an `Ok()`, but I changed to `ReturnToAction()`. I can't understand what is happening...

Here's my controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var filialOriginId = await _user.GetOriginFilial();

        if (filialOriginId == null)
            return View(@"Views/Company/NotFound.cshtml");

        var company = await _companyApplicationService.GetByOriginId(filialOriginId);

        return View(company);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [Route("save-company-options")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCompanyOptions(RegisterCompanyOptionViewModel registerCompanyOptionViewModel)
    {
        var filial = await _companyApplicationService.GetByOriginId(await _user.GetOriginFilial());
        var company = await _companyApplicationService.RegisterOptions(filial.Id, registerCompanyOptionViewModel);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
<form asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="SaveCompanyOptions" method="post">
<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="panel__title">
            Configurações
        </div>
        <p class="panel_description">Escolha o endereço da sua página, fontes e cores</p>


        <div class="panel_content flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="sm__100 md__100 lg__33 xl__33">
                <div id="Url__field"
                     class="form-floating has-prefix">
                    <input id="inputUriName"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Personalizar URL"
                           aria-describedby="Personalizar URL"
                           placeholder="Personalizar URL"
                           asp-for="@Model.UriName"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputUrlPagina">Personalizar URL</label>
                    <span class="input__prefix">@AppSettingsConfiguration.UrlBNE.Replace("https://", "")/jobs/</span>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__33 xl__33">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <select class="form-select"
                            id="selectTypography"
                            asp-for="Typography"
                            required>
                    </select>
                    <label for="selectTypography">Tipografia</label>

                    <script>
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#selectTypography option[value='@Model.Typography']").prop('selected', true);
                        }, 1000);

                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__33 xl__33">
                <div id="InputColor" class="form-floating">
                    <input id="ChangeColor"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Alterar Cor"
                           aria-describedby="Altrar Cor"
                           placeholder="Alterar Cor"
                           asp-for="Color"
                           value="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Color) ? "#00796B" : Model.Color)" />


                    <label class="form-label" for="selectTypography">Alterar Cor</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="Description" class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Como é trabalhar na @Model.Name?
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowTitle,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkHow"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="panel_description">Escolha o endereço da sua página, fontes e cores</p>
        <div class="form-floating panel_content">
            <textarea id="HowIsText" class="editor" asp-for="Title">@Model.Title</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Video institucional
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowVideo,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ckechVideo"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="panel_description">Sua empresa tem um vídeo sobre a cultura interna? Mostre-o aqui</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel_content flex flex-wrap">
            <div class="sm__100 md__100 lg__50 xl__50">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="urlVideo"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Link do Vídeo"
                           aria-describedby="Link do Vídeo"
                           placeholder="Link do Vídeo"
                           value="@Model.UrlVideo"
                           asp-for="UrlVideo"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Link do Vídeo</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm__100 md__100 lg__50 xl__50">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="urlChannel"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Link do Canal"
                           aria-describedby="Link do Canal"
                           placeholder="Link do Canal"
                           value="@Model.TwitterUrl"
                           asp-for="TwitterUrl"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Link do Canal</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container Media d-none">
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Video institucional
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowSubtitle,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkWhy"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="panel_description pb-3">Sua empresa tem um vídeo sobre a cultura interna? Mostre-o aqui</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating panel_content">
            <textarea id="whyWork" class="editor" asp-for="Subtitle">@Model.Subtitle</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Profissões que contratamos
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowJobs,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkJobs"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="panel_description pb-3">Exibir lista de vagas na sua página inicial</p>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container d-none">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Dúvidas Frequentes
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowFaq,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkFAQ"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card  flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
        <div class="flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="panel__title">
                Redes Sociais
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowSocial,new { @class="form-check-input"} )
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkSocial"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="panel_description">Escolha o endereço da sua página, fontes e cores</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel_content flex flex__wrap sm__100 md__100 lg__100 xl__100">
            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__25 xl__25">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="socialFb"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Facebook"
                           aria-describedby="input-Facebook"
                           placeholder="Facebook"
                           value="@Model.FacebookUrl"
                           asp-for="FacebookUrl"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Facebook</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__25 xl__25">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="socialLi"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Linkedin"
                           aria-describedby="input-Linkedin"
                           placeholder="Linkedin"
                           value="@Model.LinkedinUrl"
                           asp-for="LinkedinUrl"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Linkedin</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__25 xl__25">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="socialIg"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Instagram"
                           aria-describedby="input-Instagram"
                           placeholder="Instagram"
                           value="@Model.InstagramUrl"
                           asp-for="InstagramUrl"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Instagram</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm__100 md__50 lg__25 xl__25">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input id="socialTw"
                           class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           aria-label="Twitter"
                           aria-describedby="Twitter"
                           placeholder="Twitter"
                           value="@Model.TwitterUrl"
                           asp-for="TwitterUrl"
                           required />
                    <label class="form-label" for="inputNome">Twitter</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn__company">
        <button id="btnSaveCompanyOptions" onclick="saveAllSettings()" type="submit">SALVAR ALTERAÇÕES</button>
    </div>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: 302 is a redirect which is what RedirectToAction does

Comment: yeah, but why locally the controller works fine?

Comment: What is not working? Your browser should follow the redirect. Are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: yes, the controller needs to execute the methods, when it is finished, she needs to redirect to Index. In testing and locally, she works fine, but in staging and production, doesn't. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The browser should follow the server redirect instruction locally and in production. What is the actual problem? Are you making an API type call to the action? Could be an issue in your view `saveAllSettings()` method, but you haven't shown that code

Comment: before, the route was used making API call with Ajax, but we migrated to do the work with Razor form, the saveAllSettings function only do an request to another route. The actual problem is: I need to return a redirect to another view, but without returning an 302 status code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `return RedirectToAction("Index");` which performs a redirect. 302 is the Html status code for a redirect.

If you don't want to perform a redirect, you could try returning the `Index` view directly from your HttpPost action (and include the company model):

```
[Authorize]
[Route("save-company-options")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCompanyOptions(RegisterCompanyOptionViewModel registerCompanyOptionViewModel)
{
    var filial = await _companyApplicationService.GetByOriginId(await _user.GetOriginFilial());
    var company = await _companyApplicationService.RegisterOptions(filial.Id, registerCompanyOptionViewModel);

    return View("Index", company);  // return Index view here
}
```

`return View("Index", company);` returns the Index view directly from the HttpPost `SaveCompanyOptions` action. Since you're returning the view from a different action, you need to provide all the data the view needs - that's why we pass the `company` object to the view here.

`return RedirectToAction("Index");` performs a redirect which calls the `Index()` action as if it was a new request.

Comment: Ahhhh, now i understanded. The route is working fine and returning the correct, i checked the header and the location header is pointing to the index route, but why the redirect don't happen?

Comment: @bini This line `return View("Index", company);` returns the `Index` view directly from the HttpPost `SaveCompanyOptions` action. If you're returning the view from a different action, you need to provide all the data the view needs - that's why we pass the `company` object to the view here. Previously, you were performing a redirect, which calls the `Index()` action as if it was a new request.

Comment: Yeah, I tried here, but i don't want to return the view in this route, i need to redirect to index route. Is there a way to return redirect without returning the 302 status code?

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is using RedirectToAction? What is the problem when redirecting? @bini

Comment: Sorry, the problem is the route not save the data, looks like the browser instantly redirects to the location header url. I think there is some configuration in our server, but i don't have access to confirm.